# Concatenate unless note

Tags: ruby

```
mails = []
mails.concat(@note.cc_emails) unless @note.cc_emails.nil?
mails.concat(@note.to_emails) unless @note.to_emails.nil?
```

Everything what I'm doing here is checking is @note.cc_emails is not nil then concatenating it in mails array.
How can I write it in more efficient way & also reduce the number of lines in the code (if possible)?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please edit your question so that the title describes the *purpose* of the code, rather than its *mechanism*.  We really need to understand the motivational context to give good reviews.  Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Code Review!  this is a small set of code, and there isn't much to what is being done here.  if you give us more to work with, like the purpose of this piece of code and how it relates to other code in your application (posting that code as well) we will likely be able to give you a better review.  Once your question has been edited we will evaluate it to be reopened.  right now there isn't enough here to review.

Comment: If you don't mind creating a new array you can use the splat operator `*`. If you splat a `nil` value it simply disappears `[*nil] #=> []`. With this in mind you could do `mails = [*@note.cc_emails, *@note.to_emails]`. Another option is making sure `cc_emails` and `to_emails` are always set and are at least an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

These things are very much a matter of preference but I would go for something like:

```
mails = [ @note.cc_emails,
          @note.to_emails ].compact.join('')
```

which tends to remain usable as you add more clauses

Comment: should add `.flatten()` before `compact()`. It looks like `cc_emails` and `to_emails` are arrays